# Finding an array item with a certain value, removing it and re-indexing array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I've come up with one solution (which I will post below), but I was wondering if there was a better, more compact maybe, way of doing it?

```
function removeImage($id) {
    $index;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($this->_images); $i++) {
        if ($this->images[$i] == $id) {
            $index = $i;
            break;
        }

        if ($i == count($this->_images)) {
            throw new Exception("No image with this ID found.");
        }
    }

    unset($this->_images[$index]);
    $this->_images = array_values($this->_images);
}
```

Comment: why are you checking the length of the array **WHILE** you're deciding if there's anything in the array to delete? it'd be far simpler to set a flag inside the loop to say  something's been deleted and check that flag after the loop completes. the if() would have to execute for every entry in the array, but you only need to do it once after the loop completes.

Comment: That's a fair point, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finding an array item with a certain value

[`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search)

Your updated code:

```
$index = array_search($id, $this->_images);
if ($index !== false) {
  unset($this->_images[$index]);
  $this->_images = array_values($this->_images);
}
```

**Note:** unless a sequential index is important, there's no reason to re-index the array if you refactor your code to use `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you kindly :) I knew there would be a better way!

Comment: No worries, I encourage you to read my posts on how to [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).